# Parse and reformat text with optionally occurring trailing characters

Tags: php, string, replace, formatting, text-parsing

Due to horrible and inconsistent formatting by a certain website we are receiving data from, I need to parse the following string and print new strings after replacing/removing one or two substrings.

```
$s = array(
    'James Cussen\'s Destructor Bot',
    'Andre Riverra\'s Quick-Runner - San francisco', 
    'Kim Smith\'s - NightBot'
);
```

Desired result:

```
James Cussen: Destructor Bot
Andre Riverra: Quick-Runner
Kim Smith: Nightbot
```

How can I parse a line with two '-' into the corresponding `Owner: name` format?

My current code:

```
$bot ='';
$creator = '';

foreach($s as $parse)
{

   //if string contains '
    if(strpos($parse,'\'') !== false)
            {

              if(substr_count ($parse, '-') > 1)
              {
                  $arr =  explode('\'', $parse);
                
                  
                  $line =  trim(substr($arr[1], 1));
                

              }
               if(strpos($parse,'–') !== false)
                 {
                 $temp = explode('–',$parse);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                 $temp =  explode('-', $parse);
                 }
            
                $arr =  explode('\'', $temp[0]);
                $creator = $arr[0];
                
                $bot =  trim(substr($arr[1], 1));
                
                
            }

    echo $creator.':'.$bot;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Is `James Cussen`'s entry really missing a `-` or is that a typo? If so, that would make it pretty difficult..

Comment: it really is missing a -, but that one is not the main problem as I can just read from the ' to the end of string it's the one with two '-' that i'm not sure how to handle since i cannot explode on '-' anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will definitely fail in the future, because of the inconsistent format the data is being delivered in, but hey, at least it works now.

```
foreach ($s as $entry):
    list($creator, $bot) = explode('\'s', $entry);
    if (substr($bot, 0, 3) !== ' - '):
        $bot = substr($bot, 0, strpos($bot, ' - '));
    else:
        $bot = substr($bot, 3);
    endif;
    echo $creator . ': ' . $bot . '<br>';
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the provided input strings, use the following pattern.

```
's          # match apostrophe, s
(?:- )?     # optionally match hyphen, soace
(.*?)       # lazily capture zero or more of any character as backreference $1
(?: - .+)?  # match space, hyphen, space, one or more of any character
$           # match the end of the string
```

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/eCARf))

```
$strings = [
    'James Cussen\'s Destructor Bot',
    'Andre Riverra\'s Quick-Runner - San francisco', 
    'Kim Smith\'s - NightBot'
];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    echo preg_replace(
             "/'s (?:- )?(.*?)(?: - .+)?$/",
             ': $1',
             $string,
             1
         );
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
James Cussen: Destructor Bot
Andre Riverra: San francisco
Kim Smith: NightBot
```